# mysql stored procedure print error message and rollback

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i am trying to write a stored procedure that will print the error message first and then rollback

i tried this but this dose not work

i am able to rollback it but in case of error it dose not print the error message

```
DELIMITER 

CREATE PROCEDURE transaction_sp ()

BEGIN

DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
BEGIN
-- ERROR
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
select "error message '%s' and errorno '%d'"------- this part in not working
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ROLLBACK;
END;

DECLARE exit handler for sqlwarning
BEGIN
-- WARNING
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 select "warning message '%s' and errorno '%d'"------- this part in not working
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ROLLBACK;
END;

START TRANSACTION;
-- ADD option 5
INSERT INTO product_option(product_id,option_id,required) VALUES(insertedProductID,5,0);
SET poid = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
INSERT INTO     product_option_value(product_option_id,product_id,option_id,option_value_id,quantity,subtract,price,pr ice_prefix,points,points_prefix,weight,weight_prefix)    VALUES(poid,insertedProductID,5,50,0,0,4.99,'+',0,'+',0,'+');

-- ADD option 12
INSERT INTO product_option(product_id,option_id,required) VALUES(insertedProductID,12,1);

-- ADD option 13
INSERT INTO product_option(product_id,option_id,required)       VALUES(insertedProductID,13,0);

COMMIT;
END
$$
```

so how can i achieve it with this stored procedure

Answer (score 21, accepted):

this worked for me

```
DELIMITER 

CREATE PROCEDURE transaction_sp ()

BEGIN

DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
BEGIN
-- ERROR
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
--select "error message '%s' and errorno '%d'"------- this part in not working
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
@p1 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT;
SELECT @p1 as RETURNED_SQLSTATE  , @p2 as MESSAGE_TEXT;
ROLLBACK;
END;

DECLARE exit handler for sqlwarning
BEGIN
-- WARNING
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
-- select "warning message '%s' and errorno '%d'"------- this part in not working
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
@p1 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT;
SELECT @p1 as RETURNED_SQLSTATE  , @p2 as MESSAGE_TEXT;
ROLLBACK;
END;

START TRANSACTION;
-- ADD option 5
INSERT INTO product_option(product_id,option_id,required) VALUES(insertedProductID,5,0);
SET poid = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
INSERT INTO     product_option_value(product_option_id,product_id,option_id,option_value_id,quantity,subtract,price,pr ice_prefix,points,points_prefix,weight,weight_prefix)    VALUES(poid,insertedProductID,5,50,0,0,4.99,'+',0,'+',0,'+');

-- ADD option 12
INSERT INTO product_option(product_id,option_id,required) VALUES(insertedProductID,12,1);

-- ADD option 13
INSERT INTO product_option(product_id,option_id,required)       VALUES(insertedProductID,13,0);

COMMIT;
END
$$
```

Comment: Bro, that's not mysql

Comment: I tried on a mysql stored procedure, and I can say it is mysql code and it works properly!

Comment: GET DIAGNOSTICS is available in 5.6.4

Comment: There is a syntax error near the first "DELIMITER". It should rather be "DELIMITER $$"  . Also, I had an issue with the comment lines, they should be removed to avoid additional error.

Answer (score 9):

This is the way how I will print error message and rollback:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name() 
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        SHOW ERRORS;  --this is the only one which you need
        ROLLBACK;   
    END; 
    START TRANSACTION;
        --query 1
        --query 2
        --query 3
    COMMIT;
END
```

If query 1, 2 or 3 will throw an error, HANDLER will catch the SQLEXCEPTION 
and SHOW ERRORS will show errors for us. Note: SHOW ERRORS should be the first statement in the HANDLER.

Comment: this is suitable for older version than 5.6.4 , from 5.6.4 GET DIAGNOSTICS is available.

Answer (score 1):

**I Simplified Procedure Error Handling.**

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE PROCNAME (
 IN  `ID` INT(11),
 OUT `MESSAGE` VARCHAR(500), 
 OUT `Q_STATUS` BOOLEAN)
BEGIN
 -- Error handling start here
 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
 BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @ERRNO = MYSQL_ERRNO, @MESSAGE_TEXT = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    SET MESSAGE = CONCAT(@MESSAGE_TEXT," : Erro code - ",@ERRNO);
    SET Q_STATUS= 0;
    ROLLBACK; -- if any error occures it will rollback changes
 END;
 -- main query start here
 START TRANSACTION;
 SELECT IAM,ID; -- THIS WILL CAUSE OF ERROR 'UNKNOWN COLUMN IAM'
 SET Q_STATUS = 1; -- IF NO ERROR QUERY STATUS WILL GIVE YOU 1
 COMMIT; -- it is necessary in transaction 

END;
```

**Also You can use this procedure as template**

You can seprate erro code for further error handling from custom error message.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I might be late to the party but in your query

```
BEGIN
-- ERROR
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
select "error message '%s' and errorno '%d'"------- this part in not working
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ROLLBACK;
END;
```

to be changed as

```
BEGIN
select "error message '%s' and errorno '%d'"; -- use missed the semicolon
ROLLBACK;
END;
```

So it will actually display error msg with column name as 'ROLLBACK' instead of print and rollback the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of MySQL treat the MESSAGE_TEXT constant as a column which causes the wrong display. This way worked perfectly for my in MySQL 8x community.

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @ERRNO = MYSQL_ERRNO, @MESSAGE_TEXT = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    SELECT 'ERROR' AS STATUS, CONCAT('MySQL ERROR: ', @ERRNO, ': ', @MESSAGE_TEXT) AS MESSAGE;
    ROLLBACK;
END;
```